# Possible to import scss when component is imported?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, sass

is there a mechanism in the react ecosystem to import sass files only when a component is loaded? For example, I may have the following structure:

```
client/
  main.scss
  routes.jsx
  main.html
imports/
  components/
    componentA/
      ComponentA.jsx
      ComponentA.scss
    componentB/
      ComponentB.jsx
      ComponentB.scss
```

Let's say `ComponentA` is used only in the public area while `ComponentB` is used only in the admin area. If I `@import` both component stylesheets into the `main.scss` file, the public will be downloading extra data they will never use. Is there any solution to this problem in the `sass` world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using meteor this is what you can do, use import in your jsx file
In your `ComponentA.jsx` file use:
`/imports/components/componentA/ComponentA.scss`

If you want to get the scss file only if you are rendering the component, then you can do a require of this file in the render method instead of using import in the file.

Here is the link :
https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#css-importing

Comment: That is fantastic, I had no idea the pre-processors did that. If you'll add this link to the answer I'll accept as the winner: https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#css-importing

Comment: Added the link you mentioned.